# Swift Type Checking Takes Too Long on Very Short Function

Tags: swift, type-inference

I have set the Swift compiler flag `-warn-long-function-bodies` to 90 milliseconds, to see which functions in my project are taking too long to compile (due to type checking).

I have the following method:

```
func someKey(_ sectionType: SectionType, row: Int) -> String {
    let suffix = row == 0 ? "top" : "content"
    return "\(sectionType)_\(suffix)"
}
```

*(`SectionType` is an String-backed enum)*

As it is above, it takes **96ms** on a 2017 MacBook Pro. The first thing I tried is to circumvent string interpolation and use `\(sectionType.rawValue)` instead of `\(sectionType)`, but now it gives me **106 ms**. Wrong move...

Next, I changed:

```
let suffix = row == 0 ? "top" : "content"
```

to:

```
let suffix = "top"
```

The warning goes away, so it is the ternary operator that is causing trouble.

I tried this instead:

```
let suffix: String = { // Note the type annotation!
    if row == 0 {
        return "top"
    }
    return "content"
}()
```

...but now it is the *closure* that takes 97 ms (the whole function, 101).

I even tried the more explicit:

```
    let suffix: String = {
        if row == 0 {
            return String("top")
        } else {
            return String("content")
        }
    }()
```

...and I get closure: 94ms; function: 98ms.

**What's going on?**

Is my 90-milliseconds limit too low? I know there was (is?) a type-checking bug with **dictionary** literals, but this seems something entirely different...?

My environment is Xcode 8.3.2 (8E2002), 
Swift: `Apple Swift version 3.1 (swiftlang-802.0.53 clang-802.0.42)`

---

**But Wait! There's more...**

I tried this function body:

```
func someKey(_ sectionType: SectionType, row: Int) -> String {
    if row == 0 {
        return "\(sectionType.rawValue)_top"
    } else {
        return "\(sectionType.rawValue)_content"
    }
}
```

...and it takes 97ms~112ms!?

---

**Addendum:** I transplanted the function and enum to a clean, minimal project (Single View Application) set up the same warning but it does not happen. I'm sure the project as a whole is affecting this one method somehow, but can't quite figure how yet...

---

**Addendum 2**: I tested the static version of my function: use fixed suffix "top" regardless of the value of `row`(this takes less than 90 ms and triggers no warning), **but** added the following `if` block:

```
func someKey(_ sectionType: SectionType, row: Int) -> String {
    if row == 0 {
        print("zero")
    } else {
        print("non-zero")
    }

    let suffix: String = "top"
    return "\(sectionType)_\(suffix)"
}
```

This takes me back to 96~98 ms! **So the problem arises when comparing row to zero?**

---

**Workaround:** I kept playing with my code and somehow discovered that if I replace the `if` block with a `switch` statement, the issue goes away:

```
func someKey(_ sectionType: SectionType, row: Int) -> String {
    let suffix: String = {
        switch row {
        case 0:
            return "top"
        default:
            return "content"
        }
    }()
    return "\(sectionType)_\(suffix)"
}
```

(I won't answer my own question because I do not consider this an explanation of what's really going on)

Comment: In answer to your question "Is 90ms too low a limit?", no. IMO this should be trivial to compile. It **could** be a type inference thing? What happens if you add type `let suffix: String = ...` to your first example?

Comment: As a side not to my comment above. There is a very good video (I'll find a link) about type checking vs type inference. The former is easy, the latter is VERY hard.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't really aware of the difference. With `let suffix: String = ...` in the original implementation, I still get ~104 ms.

Comment: Check out this vid :D https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbjoA5xVUq0 Odd that you're still getting a long compile time though :( What happens if you change the return line of the first example to a static thing like `return "Hello, world!"`? Just to check if it's the first line or it's the interpolation in the last line.

Comment: See my edits. Looks as though comparing `row == 0` is causing some trouble...?

Comment: What is the compile time without the comparison? (set the "long time" limit to like 5ms to trigger warning again).

Comment: I didn't want to try that before for fear of the million warnings (it's a big project)... I get 49 ms

Comment: From my testing I have found 
1. String interpolation can take time "\(sectionType)_\(suffix)"
2. String constructors can take time: `String("top")` (presumably because of the overloaded constructor)

Comment: just for science, can you try UInt?

Comment: @ItamarManor I moved to a new job; I no longer have access to this code base.

Comment: Can you look at my answer and give it a tick if you you think it answers it, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's the ternary operator.

I had similar results in Xcode 11 (~93ms) but the compile time decreases to ~23ms with:

```
func someKey(_ sectionType: SectionType, row: Int) -> String {

    var suffix = "top"

    if row != 0 {
        suffix = "content"
    }

    return "\(sectionType)_\(suffix)"
}
```

By changing the logic on this line, I think we can prove it's the ternary logic because the method reduces to ~1ms. I've just made row a Boolean.

```
func someKey(_ sectionType: SectionType, row: Bool) -> String {
    let suffix = row ? "top" : "content"
    return "\(sectionType)_\(suffix)"
}
```

Equally (no pun intended) changing the ternary logic to `let suffix = row != 0 ? "top" : "content"` halves the compile time. Which is comparable to my first code block. `!=` is faster for Swift to understand than `==`.